# How to serialize into an App local storage a class derived from ParseObject?

Tags: c#, serialization, parse-platform, uwp

Working with Parse.com, I have a subclass like this:

```
[DataContract]
[ParseClassName("Event")]
public class TestDerivedObject : ParseObject
{
    [DataMember]
    [ParseFieldName("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    [ParseFieldName("description")]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(); }
        set { SetProperty(value); }
    }
}
```

When I try to save an instance of such object:

```
ApplicationDataContainer _localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
_localSettings.Values["Test"] = myTestDerivedObject ;
```

It raises an exception:

> WinRT information: Error trying to serialize the value to be written
>   to the application data store
>
> Additional information: Data of this type is not supported.

How can I save safely an object like this to my local storage? I saw that in Android implementation you can use a `Pin` method that does it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 (UWP) doesn't allow you to store a complex object in the `LocalSettings` dictionary.

> Most of the Windows Runtime data types are supported for app settings:
>
> - UInt8, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, Single, Double
> - Boolean
> - Char16, String
> - DateTime, TimeSpan
> - GUID, Point, Size, Rect
> - ApplicationDataCompositeValue
>
> You can't directly assign other types of objects to app data. You can serialize data to one of the supported data types, for example you can serialize your data as JSON and store it as a string, but you need to handle the serialization.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx)

So you'll have to serialize to a string yourself. In my opinion the easiest way is using JSON.NET to serialize to JSON:

```
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTestDerivedObject);
```

---

Update (brought to me by [@Depechie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613087/depechie))

It looks like you're basicly [screwed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418923/serializing-and-deserializing-type-that-extends-ienumerablekeyvaluepairstring) because you're using `Parse.com` objects. As these objects are a PITA to be serialized because they implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`. A possible solution would be using e.g. `AutoMapper` to map the `Parse.com` object to another self-defined type (or map the properties manually) and serialize your own type.